# Own yum repository – strange package naming with Oracle JDK

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

I just created a custom YUM repository via `createrepo` on one of our servers and made the other ones aware of it. I have three RPMs in the repository:

```
[foo@one repository]$ ls
jdk-7u4-linux-x64.rpm  jdk-7u79-linux-x64.rpm  jdk-8u65-linux-x64.rpm  repodata
```

Now when I search for available packages I get the following output:

```
[foo@two ~]$ sudo yum list available jdk*
Available Packages
jdk.x86_64            2000:1.7.0_79-fcs     
jdk1.8.0_65.x86_64    2000:1.8.0_65-fcs
```

Some servers are supposed to have Java 8 already and some still need to be updated and are running Java 7. To upgrade this smoothly, I would to configure Ansible to install a certain Java package depending on what node he is talking to.

Of course I can say install `jdk` on the Java 7 servers and install `jdk1.8.0_65` on the Java 8 servers, but this seems kind of risky.

Now my question: Why is the version included in the Java 8 rpm and why is it omitted for Java 7? And is there a way to make the version 7 explicit in the package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not strange, it's the way oracle decided to choose the names.

For 1.7 version the jdk package name is "jdk", they have [The epoch Tag](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html) set to 2000 and various versions (1.7.0_79-fcs, 1.7.0_25-fcs).

This way you could do updates to the package and install the package by doing "yum install jdk"

Starting with 1.8 they decided to use for each version a different package name. So, the package name is now "jdk1.8.0_65", epoch is "2000" and version is "1.8.0_65-fcs".

This way you can't install anymore a "standard" package (jdk), you need to know the name of it: "yum install jdk1.8.0_65". The advantage is that you can install multiple jdks and use which ever you want.